# https://api.dropbox.com/1/account/info generating an Invalid OAuth request

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

Got my tokens and can call the core API, but when I call

https://api.dropbox.com/1/account/info

I get a

```
{"error": "Invalid OAuth request."}
```

According to the documentation (https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#account-info) there are no parameters except the locale, only the GET, which is suspicious.

The use-case I am exercising validates if the access token wasn't revoked by checking the current user's account info.

I am accessing the core-api via HTTP and not via the libraries provided (Python, Ruby, PHP, ...)

Comment: The URL looks right, so my guess would be something else about the request is wrong. Are you using OAuth 1 or OAuth 2? What does your `Authorization` header look like? (But please don't share any secrets here... put in a fake token if you're going to share.)

Comment: I have the same problem, this is for OAuth 1.0. I've tried OAuth 2.0 as well, but in neither case does it work. I'm using Google App Engine, and with Dropbox OAuth 2.0 doesn't work because Dropbox require Callback URI in HTTPS, but GAE seems to not support them. So i receive error in Casting HTTPS into HTTP (that is protocol used for free app). So i really don't know how to use Dropbox API. Maybe nobody knows how to fix that...

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your access token in your url connection by setting the authorization header with your token.

```
System.out.println("accesstoken:" + access_token);
String token="Bearer ";
token+=access_token;
if (access_token != null) {
URL url = new URL(
"https://api.dropbox.com/1/account/info?locale=English");
connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

This works for me.